# How can I create header starting with1

Tags: python, pandas

I loaded the data without header.

```
train = pd.read_csv('caravan.train', delimiter ='\t', header=None)
train.index = np.arange(1,len(train)+1)
train
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   33  1   3   2   8   0   5   1   3   7
2   37  1   2   2   8   1   4   1   4   6
3   37  1   2   2   8   0   4   2   4   3
4   9   1   3   3   3   2   3   2   4   5
5   40  1   4   2   10  1   4   1   4   7
```

but the header started from 0, and I want to create header starting with 1 insteade of 0
How can I do this?

Comment: `train.columns = list(range(1, train.shape[1]+1))`  ?

Comment: Or same way as you did `index`: `train.columns = np.arange(1, train.shape[1] + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)+1
df
Out[99]: 
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1  33   1   3   2   8   0   5   1   3   7
2  37   1   2   2   8   1   4   1   4   6
3  37   1   2   2   8   0   4   2   4   3
4   9   1   3   3   3   2   3   2   4   5
5  40   1   4   2  10   1   4   1   4   7
```